# Local variables when defining function in Mathematica

Tags: mathematica

I defined a function in Mathematica.  It is a function of n, so f[n_]:=, but in the definition, I used a sum, $\sum_{k=0}^n$.  So, the $k$ is just an index variable for the sum and no $k$ shows up in the final answer.  As I was using this function I tried evaluating f[k-1] and got a weird answer, 0.  I finally figured out that Mathematica was trying to do the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{k-1}$, or so I guess.  So, my question is, is there a way to make the $k$ local so that this error never occurs?  My fix for now was to change $k$ to $index$ and I will probably not use f[index] at any point.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your result, but no luck. Could you post your function? What version are you using?

Comment: Just about anything will do... g[n_]:=$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}$ and then g[k-1] will yield 0 in Version 7.

Comment: Huh, yeah. In version 8 too. But g[n_]:= $\sum_{k=0}^n k^2$ works fine.

Comment: So, maybe it's the Binomial coefficient being 0 that is causing the problem.

Comment: @Numth @Calle I cannot reproduce this in 8.  The help for "Sum" states "The iteration variable i is treated as local, effectively using Block."  Your function g (square or Binomial version) works fine as-is or protected with 'Block' or 'Module'.  I'm commenting because I *do* run into similar problems on occasion and haven't yet been able to characterize them, so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Even with the Binomial coefficient?

Comment: @Numth @Calle @whuber: Mathematica make the summation index local using Block. In this way $k$ has a local value for the `Sum` function. However, $k$ is still $k$ so that `g[k-1]` translates into `Sum[Binomial[k-1,k],{k,0,k-1}]` which will evaluate to 0 (because Binomial[k-1,k]=0). What you want is that the summation index gets a different name and therefore you need `Module`. With `Module` the `g[k-1]` is effectively translated into `Sum[Binomial[k-1,k$],{k$,0,k-1}]`.

Comment: @whuber, yes, they both work with Block or Module. @Fabian, what I find strange is that i don't get strange results when I use a $k^2$ instead of the binomail coefficient.

Comment: @Calle @Fabian My point is that *I have no problems at all.*  For example, with `g[n_] := Sum[Binomial[n, k], {k, 0, n}]`, the result of `g[k-1]` is `2^(-1+k)`, which is correct.

Comment: @whuber That is the result I got when I did g[n_]= without the :.  But, when I do g[n_]:=, I do get 0 for g[k-1].

Comment: @Numth Thank you.  I double-checked and was able to reproduce your results.  (a) After quitting all kernels and re-evaluating the definition of g, I obtain zero for g[k-1].  (b) After issuing `Remove[k]`, I get the correct result.  (c) Protecting g with either `Block` or `Module` makes it work correctly.  Clearly, then, the help statement is not entirely correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function you are looking for is called `Module`. You can define it as

`f[n_] := Module[{k}, Sum[a[k], {k,0,n}]]`

so that the evaluation `f[k-1]` is possible.

Comment: That is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`Block` might be better than `Module` -- when you use recursion, a local variable defined in `Module` will be shared across stack frames, `Block` will have a separate version of the variable in each call

Comment: @Bulatov: but Block will not work for the OP's problem...

Comment: @Fabian Why not? I tried your snippet in Mathematica 8 and replacing `Module` with `Block` makes no difference

Comment: defining g[n_]:=Block[{k},Sum[Binomial[n,k],{k,0,n}] and then executing g[k-1] gives a result different from 0? (then they must have changed something going to version 8)

Comment: @Fabian I was too hasty, you are right, it doesn't work for that example, another approach might be to use `Unique`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to `Module` or `Block` is to use [Formal Symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/character/FormalK.html).  This allows for the cleanest code.

One may still run into trouble depending on how you choose to use Formal symbols elsewhere, but if you never use `\[FormalK]` in the argument to `f` you are safe.